# Parsing ICS file with bash

Tags: bash, file, parsing, icalendar

This is a google calendar ics file.

I download it each time to check whether new play events have been added or changed and I appear on IRC.

I need convert a file like this :

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160612T201000Z
DTEND:20160612T211000Z
DTSTAMP:20160519T200239Z
UID:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@google.com
CREATED:20160518T153226Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20160518T153226Z
LOCATION:OCS Choc
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Ash vs Evil Dead Saison 1 Episode 9 & 10
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Brussels:20160611T203500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Brussels:20160611T233500
DTSTAMP:20160519T202440Z
UID:xxxxxxxx@google.com
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Europe/Brussels:20160611T203500
CREATED:20160503T144152Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20160518T123213Z
LOCATION:RTS Un (Suisse)
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:The Mysteries Of Laura Saison 2 Episode 1 à 4
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
```

to

```
New Events Created :
dim. juin 12  20:10  Ash vs Evil Dead Saison 1 Episode 9 & 10 - OCS Choc

Last Modified Event :
sam. juin 11  20:35  The Mysteries Of Laura Saison 2 Episode 1 à 4 - RTS Un (Suisse)
```

I need convert with a bash script. 
I have to get :

DTSTART
CREATED
LAST-MODIFIED
LOCATION
SUMMARY

And i need compare CREATED and LAST-MODIFIED

pseudo-code :

```
if (created = LastModified)
then 
     echo createdevent
else
     echo lastModifiedEvent
fi
```

Comment: Ahh -- you want local dates? What's your locale?

Comment: @charles-duffy I want to search with the date of day.
I used this for my variables beta release scripts:

`dateOfDay=$(date +%Y%m%d)`

Comment: your output shows dates in a human language. Is that genuinely part of your intended output, or is it only important the filter be for today?

Comment: Frankly, btw, I'm tempted to argue that filtering by date is beyond the scope of your initial question, and that both JNevill and myself have answered the question as it was asked (except, perhaps, for failure to convert timestamps into localtime human representation, since your output shows `dim. juin 12  20:10` rather than `20160612T201000`). Questions that grow with new feature requests after being answered per their initial scope are somewhat frowned on here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 
I'm really sorry for added functionality , this is how 4h I seek me out and seeing your answer I think that it's great code , much better than mine ^^ . I want her well rested a question you will make a little more reputation : P . In my initial issue timestamps are converted , but that's not the biggest problem because on my system I have managed has worked to a method but it gives me results in the wrong order as : `OCS Chocvil Dead Saison 1 Episode 9 & 10`

Comment: Ahh -- that sounds like the input file has CRLFs -- DOS newlines. That would explain why nobody copying-and-pasting the ICS file from your question sees the problem, because when we copy-and-paste onto a UNIX system we get UNIX newlines. Okay, this is a straightforward fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A native bash implementation (for shell version 4.0 or newer -- older versions lack associative arrays) would look something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

handle_event() {
  : # put a definition of your intended logic here
}

declare -A content=( ) # define an associative array (aka map, aka hash)
declare -A tzid=( )    # another associative array for timezone info

while IFS=: read -r key value; do
  value=${value%$'\r'} # remove DOS newlines
  if [[ $key = END && $value = VEVENT ]]; then
    handle_event # defining this function is up to you; see suggestion below
    content=( )
    tzid=( )
  else
    if [[ $key = *";TZID="* ]]; then
      tzid[${key%%";"*}]=${key##*";TZID="}
    fi
    content[${key%%";"*}]=$value
  fi
done
```

...where `handle_event` is a function that does the actual work you care about. For instance, that might look like this:

```
local_date() {
  local tz=${tzid[$1]}
  local dt=${content[$1]}
  if [[ $dt = *Z ]]; then
    tz=UTC
    dt=${dt%Z}
  fi
  shift

  if [[ $dt = *T* ]]; then
    dt="${dt:0:4}-${dt:4:2}-${dt:6:2}T${dt:9:2}:${dt:11:2}"
  else
    dt="${dt:0:4}-${dt:4:2}-${dt:6:2}"
  fi

  # note that this requires GNU date
  date --date="TZ=\"$tz\" $dt" "$@"
}

handle_event() {
  if [[ "${content[LAST-MODIFIED]}" = "${content[CREATED]}" ]]; then
    echo "New Event Created"
  else
    echo "Modified Event"
  fi
  printf '%s\t' "$(local_date DTSTART)" "${content[SUMMARY]}" "${content[LOCATION]}"; echo
}
```

With your given input file and the above script, `bash parse-ics <test.ics` yields the following output (with my current locale, timezone and language):

```
New Event Created
Sun Jun 12 15:10:00 CDT 2016    Ash vs Evil Dead Saison 1 Episode 9 & 10        OCS Choc
Modified Event
Sat Jun 11 15:35:00 CDT 2016    The Mysteries Of Laura Saison 2 Episode 1 à 4   RTS Un (Suisse)
```

Comment: @SaberPendragon, zsh isn't bash. If you want an answer for zsh, don't put "with bash" in your question title.

Comment: i have GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) Sorry for mistakes..

Comment: @SaberPendragon, I've amended to add output (and stop hardcoding the input name, and ignore timezone info). If the script still doesn't work as amended, can you describe exactly how it differs?

Comment: I have no way out by running the command line :(
output : `λ  /data  → bash parse-ics <basic.ics
λ  /data  →`

Comment: Please run `curl -F 'f:1=<-' ix.io <basic.ics` to post a byte-for-byte copy of your `basic.ics` online so I can try to reproduce that issue.

Comment: ahh -- actually, per comments on the question, I think I figured out the problem to be caused by DOS newlines. I've updated the answer to handle those. Better now?

Comment: it works !!! I do not think the .ics file google was generated via DOS. Especially as I had wget . I rest a question to find out how this script executed via crontab seeking new events every hour ?

Comment: ICS is a standard that originally started on the Windows platform, so it makes (unfortunate) sense for DOS newlines to be part of the spec.

Comment: re: asking a new question, by the way -- I would suggest factoring the ICS parts out. So, for instance, if you specified that you have dates that could be either in format `20160518T153226Z` or `TZID=Europe/Brussels:20160611T233500` and you want to find only those that are in the current date in your timezone, that would be a pretty good question on its own.

Comment: Actually, let me provide a hint -- I'd hope you could modify the `handle_event` function to do the filtering yourself. It's not very hard to compare `"$(local_date DTSTART '+%Y%m%d')"` and `"$(date '+%Y%m%d')"` to see if they match, for instance, and return from the function without doing anything further if they do.

Comment: I have `TZID=Europe/Paris:20160525T040000` `TZID=Europe/Brussels:20160611T233500` and `20160518T153226Z` and i dont care about timezones except display with the Paris timezone. And i have posted new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335616/display-only-the-last-hour-event-created-or-modified-with-an-ics-file

Comment: A minor addition: If you change the line `done` to `done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"` the script will also work with the ICS file as a command-line argument.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy, true, but that's creating an extra `open()` and `fdup()` even when they aren't needed at all, so it's not a pattern I'm much fond of. I'd rather do a `if [ "$1" ]; then exec <"$1"; fi` before the `while` loop is entered.

Answer (score 5):

`awk` is useful for stuff like this. The following can be placed in a new file (ics.awk):

```
BEGIN{OFS=" "}
$1=="DTSTART"{DTSTART=$2}
$1=="CREATED"{CREATED=$2}
$1=="LAST-MODIFIED"{LASTMODIFIED=$2}
$1=="SUMMARY"{SUMMARY=$2}
$1=="LOCATION"{LOCATION=$2}
$1=="END"{
        if (CREATED==LASTMODIFIED)
                print "\nNew Event Created"
        else
                print "\nLast Modified Event"

        print DTSTART,SUMMARY,LOCATION
}
```

You can execute it like:

```
awk -F":" -f ics.awk yourfile.ics
```

That splits the fields in the file by a colon and the awk script processes the file line by line. It captures values as it finds it, then prints them when it finds a line with "END".

The script above will get you close:

```
New Event Created
20160612T201000Z Ash vs Evil Dead Saison 1 Episode 9 & 10 OCS Choc

Last Modified Event
20160612T201000Z The Mysteries Of Laura Saison 2 Episode 1 à 4 RTS Un (Suisse)
```

Comment: Nice. I'd recommend this if the OP doesn't have bash 4 or newer on their target platform.

Comment: @JNevill

I get this result with my ics file :

`New Event Created`
`OCS Chocvil Dead Saison 1 Episode 9 & 10`

`Last Modified Event`
`RTS Un (Suisse)f Laura Saison 2 Episode 1 à 4`

Did I miss something?

Comment: @SaberPendragon That suggests that "DTSTART" and "LOCATION" is not the right value for the first field since Awk isn't finding that in the first field of any of the records, thus the variable is not being set, thus it's not printing.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same logic as [@JNevill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill) but with associative arrays:

ics.awk

```
BEGIN { FS=":" }
{ a[$1] = $2 }
$1 == "END" {
  printf("%s\n%s %s %s\n\n", 
    a["CREATED"] == a["LAST-MODIFIED"] ? "New Event Created" : "Last Modified Event", 
    a["DTSTART"], a["SUMMARY"], a["LOCATION"])
}
```

And then call it with:

```
% awk -f ics.awk input-file
New Event Created
20160612T201000Z Ash vs Evil Dead Saison 1 Episode 9 & 10 OCS Choc

Last Modified Event
20160612T201000Z The Mysteries Of Laura Saison 2 Episode 1 Ã  4 RTS Un (Suisse)
```

Will leave a trailing new line however.

Comment: Note that the question shows dates in localtime format in the desired-output section (which, as each field can have a different timezone specified, can be an interesting problem), and parsing actual ICS files requires dealing gracefully with DOS newlines in input.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ pip install mutt-ics

$ mutt-ics event.ics

Subject:  DCP IP Seminar 2023
Start:    Friday, 26 May 2023, 08:30 CEST
End:      Friday, 26 May 2023, 17:00 CEST
Location: Auberge du Pêcheur (Pontstraat 41, 9831 Sint-Martens-Latem)
```

Here is more information about creating a [`text/calendar` MIME type](https://www.softwolves.com/wolfblog/2021/11/03/reading-icalendar-ics-file-from-outlook-on-linux/) for processing with a graphical e-mail client.